How does an impact driver hammer and spring mechanism cam backwards when loosening fastenings?
For an electric impact driver / impact wrench, how does the hammer mechanism cam backwards and forwards? In reverse (loosening fastenings), the spring twisting would cause spring extension, not compression. There seems to be some cam mechanism between the hammer and the shaft, as shown in the images. Is there a ball bearing inside this mechanism? How does it operate?
From my understanding, the motor/gearbox output is directly connected to the spring, which connects to the hammer. The hammer also interfaces with the shaft through some ball bearing / cam system which I am unsure about.
See attached image as well.

https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-x3f68rvsei/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/295/1607/DSC00462__05349.1602110462.JPG?c=1

So where are the rest of the parts? What links or joins them together? A complete drawing would be most useful.
